# Stop Timer that was started in a function

Tags: javascript, timer

I have started this timer from within a function but i cant get it to stop with `clearInterval` and if i run the function again it just makes it go twice as quick.

```
var TimerID;


    function StartTimer(){
    $(document).ready(function() {
    time=20;var Timer=document.getElementById('Timer');tmp=time;

    var TimerID = setInterval(function(){

                var c=tmp--,m=(c/60)>>0,s=(c-m*60)+'';
                Timer.textContent=m+':'+(s.length>1?'':'0')+s
                tmp!=0||(tmp=time);

        },1000);    



     });}
```

.

```
clearInterval(TimerID);
```

Comment: When you add the keyword `var` to the inner `TimerID` it gives it function scope... remove `var` to globally scope it to the outer `TimerID`.

Answer (score 4):

Remove `var TimerID = setInterval(function(){` and make it

```
TimerID = setInterval(function(){
```

Using `var TimerID = setInterval(function(){` is going to cause TimerID to become a local variable inside of the document.ready callback function. As a result of being local to that scope, it will not be accessible outside of the callback function.

Removing the `var` will allow the TimerID variable outside of the callback function's scope to be used which is what seems to be the intention.

Comment: Just to clarify this a bit, removing `var` will set this in a global context and will make it available basically everywhere else in your code.

Comment: @Scheda - In his code, you can see that he has already defined a `TimerID` variable, so it will be available to whichever scope that is  regardless.

Comment: Ah yeah. I guess if I had looked at it more closely I would have known that :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the 'var' within your function. Your redefining timerid in your function scope. You want to use the one from the global scope.